# AIR iOS TextField doesn't dispatch mouse or touch events after focussed (AS3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, mouseevent, textfield

I'm having a terrible time of getting a TextField, once focussed, to dispatch any mouse related events.  On Android, AIR *does* dispatch mouse events, but nothing in iOS.

Specifically, I'm looking for the MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_MOVE, and MOUSE_UP events, or the same touch states.

I've tried setting Mouse and Touch events on the Stage, on the TextField, on objects above the TextField, and even tried NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(TouchEvent/MouseEvent), though that last one seems to be a non-starter.  I've also tried just watching the Stage.mouseX and mouseY properties, but they go silent once the TextField gets focus.

I'm using Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT out of necessity.

Events are fired if the TextField is not focussed, but I get nothing once it is.  ANY help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because TextField component (only for iOS) is a couple of two components:
1. When it have no focus or not editable and not selectable - Flash's TextField
2. When it have focus for editing - native iOS's UITextView. It will be shown on the highest layer above you Flash's TextField.
For get back Flash's TextField you can use stage.focus (or .setFocus?) method.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The problem is that I need to be able to move the *already focussed* TextField with a mouse-drag right on the TextField itself.  I don't actually care whether or not it loses focus after the drag begins, but the drag needs to begin while the TextField is still focussed.  Again, I'm trying to drag a TextField that has focus, using the TextField itself as a surface.  It appears that the TextField is absorbing/ignoring any kind of Mouse/Touch event, so my listeners get nothing.  This works in Android gosh darn it!

Comment: If you need fully interaction with native UICompnents, you can create the simple ANE (AIR Native extension) with "redispatching" touch events.

Comment: Yes, I've thought this might be the path ever since I ran into the problem.  Alas, it is rather beyond my knowledge to make one.  Can you point me to a tutorial on making an ANE that uses display components?

Answer (score 0):

Can stagetext fulfill your usecase instead of flash.text.textfield?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I should have mentioned that this also doesn't work.  No touch/mouse events are propagated to my listeners if they occur within the bounds of either a TextField or StageText.

So my next question is: does anyone want a commission to make an ANE text box that gives me mouse and/or touch events?

Comment: I do not know your exact use case. But what about listening to focusIn and focusOut on the stagetext and then dispatch your own event from the event handlers to the displaylist.

Comment: Well you see, that's just it, I'm not going to get a focusIn or focusOut or *anything* other than keyboard events, because the touch/mouse I'm looking for is happening *inside* the TextField after it's already in focus.  Touching it again after it's already in focus doesn't defocus it, or re-focus it.  It seems to be a total touch/mouse black hole.  Thanks for the thought, though.  So I will ask again - anyone out there capable of writing an ANE that either (a) just gives me raw global touch events from iOS, or (b) can provide the missing touch events (in any form) to my app?